# Increase upload file size by content type

Tags: 7, files

I have worked with our host to increase our upload file size to 2GB.  However, on one page it still states that the files must be less than 3MB.  How do I change that?  I am a Drupal novice so please bear that in mind.

The following is on a content type on our website (classified as a 'story'):

> Files must be less than 3 MB. Allowed file types: jpg jpeg gif png txt
>   doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp.

So I am trying to increase the size to be 2GB as per what our host is allowing. How do I increase the file size to upload?

Comment: Can you even upload a file that size without a timeout?

Comment: I am not getting and error (not yet anyway).  The following is on a page on our website (classified as a 'story)  "Files must be less than 3 MB.
Allowed file types: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp."  I am trying to increase the size to be 2GB as per what our host is allowing.  How do I increase the file size to upload?  I apologize if I am not clear.  Please let me know if this helps you.  Thank you.

Comment: Kevin,  we have on a different 'page'  at which our limit is 1GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the content type "story" has a 3MB limit set on that file field.

You can increase that limit by browsing to "example.com/admin/structure/types" and select the "Manage fields" tab (for the "story" content type). Find the field in question (the file upload field) and edit it. You should find a setting for the maximum upload size there.

If you'd like to learn more about fields, and specifically file fields, check out [this Drupal.org resource](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/working-with-content-types-and-fields-drupal-7-and-later) and and [this one as well](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file).

Now, the other thing you will need to review is your [.htaccess file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/installing-drupal-7/step-3-create-settingsphp-and-the-files-directory). There are a couple of php flags you will want to review:

```
php_value post_max_size
php_value upload_max_filesize
```

Review the .htaccess file first because no matter what setting you set for your file field on the content type "story", it will be overridden by the setting in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Shane et al,  thank you for your responses and assistance in solving this.  And thanks for the education on 'content type', that helps!

Comment: BTW  the .htaccess file does not have anything for max size, this is what it has this:  # Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. 

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the .htaccess change is not required for your issue @javablood , as only one type of content was being affected. Some others may need to use the .htaccess fix for site-wide problems. P.S. please mark this answer as accepted if it fixed your issue. Glad we could help :)

Comment: How do I mark it as answered?  Told you I was a Drupal novice!  :-)  I only see "Answer Your Question" and it did not look like that was it.

Comment: There should be a check mark to the left of this answer that you can check to accept the answer. That's the case for all "Stack Exchange" communities like this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: ah, the old check mark routine eh? got it.